# How is it possible to include a .blade file from outside of the Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have a Laravel 5.8 project and I'm using Blade to display the website.

However, I have `.blade` files outside of the Laravel project, that I'd like to `@include()` or display from the controller with `return view();` with blade.

Here is a similar folder structure:

```
/var/www/examplesite1/
/var/www/examplesite2/
/var/www/laravel/
/var/www/storage/blade/
```

So for example the Laravel application is on the `/var/www/laravel/` path. The blade file I'd like to get is from this path `/var/www/storage/blade/`.

**What I tried was:**

```
return view('/var/www/storage/blade/file.blade.php');

include('/var/www/storage/blade/file.blade.php');
```

None of them worked, becauase I got an error like this: `View [.var.www.storage.blade.file.blade.php] not found.`

I also tried it with omitting the 'blade.php' from the end, but it's the same.

Is it possible to include a blade file from outside the Laravel project? If yes, how?

Comment: Laravel expects to find views in the `resources/views` directory within the project root: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#creating-views. What is it you're trying to achieve by keeping them outside the project?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but to include external .php file you can do something like 

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../../any_file.php');

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] will lead you to Laravel public folder.

Comment: This may be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). **Why** do you want to do it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add new directories to the views paths in `config/views.php`. https://laravel-news.com/laravel-view-path